# Option clash for package footmisc

Tags: packages, footnotes, footmisc, option-clash

I'm trying to use the footmisc package to move my footnotes down, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to stop the option clash.

Here is the preamble of my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\DeclareMathOperator\arcsinh{arcsinh}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=0.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {c:/images/}}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ragged2e` package loads `footmisc` with some options, so you cannot load it again with a different set of options.

You can pass the `bottom` option to `ragged2e`, because it is set up so that uknown options are passed to `footmisc`. Do

```
\usepackage[document,bottom]{ragged2e}
```

and remove `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks so much :)

Comment: @egreg What is a more general approach for identifying the cause of option clashes?

Comment: @ashman Unfortunately there’s no general way. The particular case is tough, because one never expects the Spanish Inquisition, nor that ragged2e` has anything to do with `footmisc`